# event dispatch thread in Java SWING program

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am totally a newbie in Java. And I want to create an animation. But I did not succeed. `mouseClicked()` will be executed in the event dispatching thread. Why doesn't it work? Will the event dispatching be occupied by other threads, what other threads?

```
public class DemoThreadGUI {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        DemoThreadGUI app = new DemoThreadGUI();
        app.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                generateGUI();
            }
        });     
    }
    public void generateGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.add(new MyPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
        private int x,y;
        private int r;
        public MyPanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
            this.addMouseListener(this);
            x = 50;
            y = 50;
            r = 25;
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.fillOval(x-r,y-r,r*2,r*2);
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            int targetX = event.getX();
            int targetY = event.getY();
            for(int i=0;i<10;++i) {
                x = (x+targetX)/2;
                y = (y+targetY)/2;
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            }
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {}

    }

}
```

Comment: *You* are the one occupying the event dispatch thread when you tell it to `sleep`. You can’t expect a thread to paint your UI when you told it to sleep. No other thread to think about.

Answer (score 1):

In your mouseClicked() start a new Thread and place the code in the thread

```
       for(int i=0;i<10;++i) {
            x = (x+targetX)/2;
            y = (y+targetY)/2;
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
```

The `repaint()` call should be wrapped into `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` to pass control to EDT

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please explain a little bit what's the change and why it works?

Answer (score 0):

As Holger said, *You can’t expect a thread to paint your UI when you told it to sleep.*

Use this instead:

- Make `targetX` and `targetY` global variables, and make a new `java.util.Thread` object `t`.

  ```
  private int x,y;
  private int r;
  Thread t;
  int targetX, targetY;
  ```
- modify your `mouseClicked` method as:

  ```
  public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent event) {
      targetX = event.getX();
      targetY = event.getY();
      t = new Thread(new Runnable(){public void run(){anim();}});
      t.start();
  }
  ```
- Put your code of the `mouseClicked` method into the `anim` method as:

  ```
  public void anim()
  {
      for(int i=0;i<10;++i) {
          try{
              x = (x+targetX)/2;
              y = (y+targetY)/2;
              repaint();
              Thread.sleep(100);
          }catch(Exception e){}
      }
      t.stop();
  }
  ```

This works perfectly.